# Ask about some functions about glkit?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glkit

Usually we need to call glport to set up the view port, is it necessary for using glkit?

For double buffer, when using glkit, do we need to use swapbuffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GLKView` class automatically maintains a framebuffer and associated renderbuffers, sets the GL viewport to match its size (and scale factor), and manages presenting a rendered frame (i.e. swapping buffers) for display. For the common case, all you need to do is implement `drawRect:` (or set a delegate and implement `glkView:drawInRect:` there) and issue GL drawing commands inside that method.